# Visual Studio intellisense/autocorrect works for C# terms, but not for Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I write code in Visual Studio, it normally highlights and suggests prompts such as `string`, `void`, method names and such.

However, it doesn't work for Unity terms such as `Vector3` or `Time`. I tried updating both and also changing the external tools settings, but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run the **Visual Studio Installer** and be sure to enable the **Game development with Unity** option

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eeI2hWgPbA Check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these steps:

Step 1:
Close Visual Studio

Step 2:
In Unity, go to Edit < Preferences < External Tools (left part of the Window)

Step 3:
In External Tools go to the part that says External Script Editor (this should be on which ever Visual Studio editor you are using (for me it defaulted to "Open by File Extension"

Step 4:
Make sure Generate all csproj files is checked, and Editor Attaching is checked

Step 5:
Open the C# script you were trying to open earlier

(source: https://forum.unity.com/threads/intellisense-not-working-with-visual-studio-fix.836599)

Comment: I already did that before, but now that I have revised this solution I found out that I have to click "Regenerate project files" for it to actually work. Thanks.